# Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo consultar o *array* de um elemento que está dentro de um *array* através de um `for..of` e quero unir os elementos do *array* com a função `join`, mas estou recebendo o erro abaixo e não sei o porquê.

**Erro:**

> ```
> Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
> ```

**Código:**

```js
var usuarios = [{
    nome: "Lucas",
    habilidaes: ["JavaScript", "NodeJS", "MongoDB", "HTML", "CSS"]
  },
  {
    nome: "Rafael",
    habilidades: ["JavaScript", "Java", "MySQL", "HTML", "CSS"]
  }
];

function leitorHabilidades(usuarios) {
  for (usuario of usuarios) {
    console.log(
      'O ' +
      usuario.name +
      ' possui habilidade em: ' +
      usuario.habilidades.join()
    );
  }
}

leitorHabilidades(usuarios);
```

Comment: Você escreveu `habilidaes` em vez de `habilidades`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é devido a um erro de digitação, você escreveu "habilidaes" em vez de "habilidades" no primeiro item do array

Na função também tem outro problema, você está buscando o "name" de cada usuário mas definiu como "nome"